# Can raw gps data for each individual satellite be extracted from android phones?

Tags: gps

I am trying to build a tight integration module between GNSS and INS. Hence i need raw satellite data. Can this be extracted from normal android phones?

Comment: on Android Nougat https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html

Answer (score 3):

Since the release of Android Nougat, an API for obtaining the raw GNSS measurements from Android phones was released. [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/gnss#release) you can find all the information for the GNSS Analysis Tools, while [here](https://sites.google.com/view/gnsstutorial) you can find a small data sample and a tutorial on how to use this API.

Comment: v2.6.0.1 Added L1-L5 analysis: L1-L5 C/No difference and L1-L5 group delay.

Comment: some background https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/gnss-analysis-tools-from-google.html